# Python 3: TypedDict Key Names

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, typeddict

I am using some nested typed dictionaries and my code is working.
However, I am not surprised to see warnings, when I use the Thonny Assistant, because I am not using string literals as key names everywhere in the dictionaries. However, Python does not complain at all and runs the code just fine.

But why is this sample code still working ?

```
from typing import TypedDict

S_Info  = TypedDict('S_Info', {'Type':int, 'Avail': bool, 'Pause': bool,'Status': int})
B_Types = TypedDict('B_Types',{0x01: S_Info, 0x02: S_Info})    

bmatrix: B_Types = {
    0x01:{
        0b000: {'Type': 0x21, 'Avail': 1, 'Pause': 0, 'Status':0},
        0b001: {'Type': 0x81, 'Avail': 1, 'Pause': 0, 'Status':2},
        0b010: {'Type': 0x41, 'Avail': 1, 'Pause': 0, 'Status':0}},
    0x02:{
        0b000: {'Type': 0x22, 'Avail': 0, 'Pause': 0, 'Status':1},
        0b001: {'Type': 0x82, 'Avail': 0, 'Pause': 1, 'Status':9},
        0b010: {'Type': 0x42, 'Avail': 0, 'Pause': 0, 'Status':0}}
    }

print(bmatrix[0x02])
```

I was expecting it to fail, because I thought I needed to use string literals. However, I tried it, because I know Python sometimes is quite forgiving and it was very handy to use hex numbers, that I can create, using binary operations somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Where does it say (book, tutorial, etc.) that Python dictionary keys **have to** be *string literals*?  Or did you mean something else?

Comment: "I was expecting it to fail," what do you mean by "to fail" and why were you expecting that?

Comment: Thanks for this hint PM 77-1.
When I learned Python dictionaries, I never saw an example, where the key was not a string literal. I sometimes use Thonny Assistant to check my code and it fires out 3 different warnings. 

Line 4 : Invalid TypedDict() field name  [misc]
Line 7 : Expected TypedDict key to be string literal  [misc]
Line 17 : TypedDict key must be a string literal; expected one of ()  [literal-required]

However, after looking up different sources, I found a hint that "an object of any immutable type can be used as a dictionary key".